# Text Editors Appending Text on Save When Characters Deleted

Tags: windows, notepad++, usb-flash-drive, fat32, visual-studio-code

When I delete text from a text file on a Windows PC with a most text editors, extra bytes get appended to the file.

- This happens when I edit a file on my FAT32 thumb drive or on a spinning-disk USB drive with NTFS.
- This does NOT happen when I copy the file to my NTFS C-drive and edit it there.
- If I make a copy of the file on my thumb drive, the problem happens with the copy too.
- The problem does not happen if I edit the file with Notepad or JEdit.
- The problem does happen if I edit with Notepad++, Sublime Text 3, Notepad2, Visual Studio Code, or WordPad.
- I replaced the thumb drive with a new one, and the problem came back.
- The problem does not happen with every text file on the thumb drive.
- Error-checking the file system reports no errors.
- After copying a file from the thumb drive to the C-drive and back to the thumb drive, the problem is NOT cured.
- The problem does not happen if I edit a problem file on the thumb drive using vi from Cygwin.
- If I move the thumb drive to another Windows PC, the issue does not happen there.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: What is your text editor?

Comment: Have you examined these extra bytes?

Comment: "Extra bytes" - do they also appear in the text editor or you see them in hex editor only?

Comment: The extra characters are characters from near the end of the original file.  They are all printable characters, according to a hex dump.  It appears as if deleting text from the top of the file leaves 'droppings' behind as the characters at the end move up.  If it weren't for the fact that it happens with multiple highly-used editors, I'd say it was an editor bug failing to properly set EOF.  I do not see the characters when I save the file, but if I exit the editor and re-open the file, I do see them.

Comment: Not McAfee.  Disabled that and the problem persisted.  Not the file extension.  Renamed the file to .txt and the problem persisted. I copied the file to a USB drive with a spinning disk and NTFS and the problem happens there (but it doesn't happen on my C-drive). Something on that machine is messing up EOF on USB drives.

Comment: Ha!  Getting closer. The problem does not happen with JEdit in its default configuration.  JEdit is renaming the old file and writing the updated content to a new file with the original name.  I think Notepad does a full file write.  It appears that editors which update the file in place are affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was enterprise security software.  We use many security packages and keep-data-confidential packages, and I believe it to be one of those.

*Any* editor which updates the file in place shows this behavior on my machine.  Editors which write the output to a new file (and rename the old file to .bak and then rename the new file to the original file name) work correctly on this machine.